# reuses "rechnung()" even though it shouldn't

Tags: c++, function, while-loop, implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funktionen.h"

using namespace std;

int rechnung()
{
    cout  << "Please choose the operator you want to calculate with" << endl;
    int eingabe1;
    int eingabe2;
    int eingabe;
    int dummy;
    char zeichen;
    char again;
    cin >> zeichen;
    cout << endl << "1. Eingabe: ";
    cin >> eingabe1;
    cout << endl << "2. Eingabe: ";
    cin >> eingabe2;
    switch (zeichen)
    {
    case '+':
        eingabe=eingabe1 + eingabe2;
        break;
    case '-':
        eingabe=eingabe1 - eingabe2;
        break;
    case '*':
        eingabe=eingabe1 * eingabe2;
        break;
    case '/':
        eingabe=eingabe1 / eingabe2;
        break;
    }

    cout << endl << "Das Ergebnis ist | " << eingabe << " | " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Wanna calculate again? ";
    cin >> again;
    while(again=='Y')
    {
        rechnung();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So this is my code in an implementation file. My problem is, that the main program always loops the whole "rechnung()" function even though I don't type "Y" into the console once it asks for it. In the beginning, when I type something else than "Y", then the console closes (as it shall) but if I do a calculation, type "Y", do another calculation and type "k" for example, it also starts from the beginning of "rechnung()". Why does it do so? I mean I told him that he shall only recall the "rechnung()" if the character input is "Y".

Comment: You never modify `again` inside the loop - the function call creates a new local variable, which has nothing to do with the one from the calling function

Comment: On a different note, there is absolutely no reason to use recursion here - you should just wrap the entire part you want to repeat inside the `while` instead

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat it inside" So I shall just write all the code, which is above the loop, again into the loop? Where is the problem of just calling the function once again?

Comment: I already explained what the problem is you are having with calling it recursively. And you shouldn't copy the code, you should move it inside the loop

Comment: So you mean I should put again='Y' in the beginning and then wrap everying with the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this maybe simpler example:

```
void foo() {}
void bar() {
    char again;
    // ... do something
    std::cin >> again;
    while(again=='Y') {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Inside the loop the value of `again` never changes, so there is an infinite loop. However, your code goes one step further by calling the function recursively. Strongly simplified you have:

```
void bar() {
   // .. do something
   while (true) {
       bar();
   }
}
```

ie `bar` is calling itself again and again and never returns. You put the loop at the wrong place. You could write it like this

```
void bar() {
    char again = 'Y';
    while (again == 'Y') {
        // .. do something
        std::cout << "repeat?";
        std::cin >> again;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tyvm, that helped alot. I changed it now and it worked :) 
It seems very plausible; but I didn't see it in the first place